# Url rewriting after switching to Virtual Hosts

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, easyphp

After a pretty steep learning curve, I've managed to create a virtual host on my machine (Windows 7 running EASY PHP v12) to serve one of the sites I'm developing. (Prior to this I'd go in and change the DocumentRoot and Directory path to the folder of the project I wanted to work on).

Without the virtual hosts, I had no problem getting url rewrites to work. The following is the .htaccess I had set up in each project

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.localhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
#RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.localhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 

RewriteBase /
```

So for example, when I would visit localhost.com/file it would take me to file.php in the root folder of the current 'server' working directory.

Since adding a virtual host with this code

```
#virtualhost
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot "c:/dropbox/newsite/site"
ServerName newsite
<Directory "c:/dropbox/newsite/site">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#virtualhost
```

I can't to seem to get the rewrite working - for example newsite/home should take me to home.php but doesn't.

Any suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You sure that the htaccess file is in "c:/dropbox/newsite/site"? What does the access/error logs say?

Comment: It is. Strangely, the error logs are blank (I cleared previous errors).

Comment: I have just worked out it's only doing this with home - it's possibly some kind of reserved word in EasyPHP. I've changed all references to home in httpd.conf (which maps to the home folder in the easyphp install directory) but it still throws an error.